# Save WPF TreeView state on data reload

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using TreeView to display my data in UI. Now my application refreshes every 5 seconds so that it shows the most current data. Is there a way I can save my expanded state or collapsed state of treeview even after window reload? Because if I have a huge amount of data and I take more than 5 seconds to go to desired data, the TreeView just collapses after every 5 seconds with window refresh, and I have to start from scratch.

```
      <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" Grid.Row="1"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource sectionTemplate}" >

        <TreeView.Resources> 
          <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"> 
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          </Style> 
        </TreeView.Resources> 

    </TreeView>

public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> =new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();

public bool IsExpanded
    {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(MyViewModel));


 if (result.TotalResults > 0)
      {
        foreach (DomainObject obj in result.ResultSet)
        {
          AT myAT= (AT)obj;
          arrdep.Add(myAT);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you recreating the Sections collection every 5 seconds?

Comment: yes..the window reloads/refreshes every 5 seconds. So I have it as an observablecollection that gets cleared and then filled with objects..

Comment: Oh well then your IsExpanded property is also getting cleared every 5 seconds. Any chance you could just update values instead of deleting them and recreating them?

Comment: Well the TreeView is a visual representation of `Sections` so by rebuilding `Sections` you are rebuilding the TreeView

Comment: Perhaps an alternative would be to build a copy of `Sections` in the CodeBehind and bind your TreeView to the copy. Anytime your actual `Sections` collection gets changed, build something to merge the changes into the copy (don't recreate the copy - instead modify existing objects with the changes or add/delete new/removed items)

Comment: I edited my code to above. I tried not to refresh the entire window but just update the data. But still the nodes won't save the state..

Answer (score 16):

I solved that problem by adding IsExpanded and IsSelected properties to the object that my TreeView was bound to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It depends on what your TreeView is binding to. If it's a list of custom objects then it's easy, just add two public boolean properties called IsExpanded and IsSelected. To set them you don't need to do anything. They will default to False and get updated when the user expands/collapses/selects the treeview items since it is using TwoWay binding

Comment: I tried to write the code as shown in my editted question above but it wont work..

Comment: It does not work for me either, I think it is wrong. Could you please be a little bit more specific?

Comment: @Manolete The `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties need to be on whatever data object the `TreeViewItem` has as it's DataContext. So if your `TreeView` binds to an `ObservableCollection<SomeItem>`, then `SomeItem` needs to have `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties

Comment: I don't think this is a beautiful solution at all, since a domain object bound to a TreeViewItem shouldn't be having information about its expansion state.

Comment: @Grochni so what's your solution?

Comment: Thanks @Rachel works fine for me it's very simple and effective.